# OpenShift Origin Quickstart error: getsockopt: no route to host 172.30.0.1 on a VM

Tags: centos, openshift-origin

I am currently trying to learn more about OpenShift Origin, and have a CentOS VM deployed on VMWare Fusion. I got the OpenShift Origin server installed and running following the OpenShift Quickstart guides. However, when I try to deploy the test application, I get the following error during deployment.

[image: Test Deployment Failure Log]

I also get the following message when adding the new-app

```
oc new-app openshift/deployment-example    
--> Found Docker image 1c839d8 (2 years old) from Docker Hub for "openshift/deployment-example"    
    * An image stream will be created as "deployment-example:latest" that will track this image    
    * This image will be deployed in deployment config "deployment-example"    
    * Port 8080/tcp will be load balanced by service "deployment-example"    
      * Other containers can access this service through the hostname "deployment-example"    
    * WARNING: Image "openshift/deployment-example" runs as the 'root' user which may not be permitted by your cluster administrator

--> Creating resources ...
    imagestream "deployment-example" created
    deploymentconfig "deployment-example" created
    service "deployment-example" created
--> Success
    **WARNING: No Docker registry has been configured with the server. Automatic builds and deployments may not function.**
```

What needs to be done to get it deployed successfully on my VM? I am not sure if the above warning message has got anything to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured my mistake that the port 8443/tcp wasn't opened. Did that using

sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8443/tcp --permanent

sudo firewall-cmd --reload

And it started working